# jQuery - Toggle between functions on click

Tags: jquery, html, animation

**Problem**
I'm trying to toggle between two functions when a button is clicked using jQuery's .toggle() method, but the button itself goes away as soon as the DOM is ready.

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#panel").css({"height": "0%", "bottom": "0"});

/*
    var already_clicked = false;
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        if (already_clicked) {
            $("#panel").animate({"height": "0%"}, 500);
            already_clicked = false;
        } else {
            $("#panel").animate({"height": "100%"}, 500);
            already_clicked = true;
        }
    });
*/

    $("button").toggle(function() {
        $("#panel").animate({"height": "100%"}, 500);
    }, function() {
        $("#panel").animate({"height": "0%"}, 500);
    });

});
```

**Markup**

```
<body>
    <div id="panel"></div>
    <button>Click me</button>
</body>
```

**Note**: The solution in the comment block works as intended, but I'm not sure why .toggle() doesn't works.

Comment: is button is inside or outside panel.?

Comment: Outside and after the panel.

Comment: paste little html code...

Comment: Which jQuery version you use?

Comment: its working nothing wrong.

Comment: @Rafay that's why - it's removed in 1.9 - see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im not to use if this is what you want but [`.slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/):

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#panel").slideToggle(500);
});
```

could be what you are asking?

Comment: Oh lordy, I didn't know this existed. This is precisely what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: `$("#panel").stop().slideToggle(500);` will do better... See http://jsfiddle.net/kFdnF/

Comment: @A.V thats what most want, but maybe Rafay want to quere up his slides :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery 1.9 then `.toggle` doesn't work like that - the version that takes two functions as arguments was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9

See http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @Liam that's where I was looking - the version the OP is trying to use is at http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ but it's deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9

Comment: How very irresponsible of me; I should have checked the docs first. Oh well, it was a good function.

Comment: Yeah, just adding to give a little extra info to the OP